# I'm facing ImportErrors while using some libraries in Python

Tags: time-series, shared-libraries

While importing these libraries

```
 from ta.trend import ATRIndicator
 from ta.trend import MACD
 from ta.momentum import RSIIndicator
 from ta.trend import ADXIndicator
 from ta.momentum import ROCIndicator
 from ta.momentum import CCIIndicator
```

, I'm facing this error; **none** of them seems to work well:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 Cell In[1], line 15
 11 import pylab as pl
 12 from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
 15 from ta.trend import ATRIndicator
 16 from ta.trend import MACD
 17 from ta.momentum import RSIIndicator
 
 ImportError: cannot import name 'ATRIndicator' from 'ta.trend' (C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\ta\trend.py)
```

I have tried `pip install ta` and `pip --upgrade ta` but none of these have worked.
I'm expecting to properly load libraries for moment oscillators for time series.